# How to write custom plugin in OpenAI using Python?

Tags: plugins, openai-api, azure-openai

I'm trying to connect a API with OpenAI using plugin option.

Couldn't find a way to connect API ( which provides user information) with Open AI using python

Methodologies and Code for Custom Plugin configurations are much appreciated